# How can i apply "Factory Pattern" to instantiate Firefox, IE and Chrome Browser instances in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

so here is what i have:

```
Browser.java
BrowserFactory.java

ChromiumBrowser.java
InternetExlorer.java
FirefoxBrowser.java
HTMLUnitBrowser.java

SeleniumDriver.java
```

What i am thinking is that SeleniumDriver.java is a client of the BrowserFactory and will create an instance of a browser depending on which one is selected via a csv file :

1. ChromiumBrowser
2. InternetExlorer
3. FirefoxBrowser
4. HTMLUnitBrowser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have loads of ways to implement a factory. It depends on how complex the creation and how fixed the list of entities.

The enum way:

```
public enum BrowserType {
    CHROME {
        public Browser create() {
            return new ChromeBrowser();
        }
    },
    IE {
        public Browser create() {
            return new IeBrowser();
        }
    }
    public abstract Browser create();
}

// Factory is optional really, the enum does the job.
public class BrowserFactor {

    public Browser create(BrowserType type) {
        return type.create();
    }
}
```

The map/strategy way:

```
interface BrowserStrategy {
    Browser create();
}

public class ChromeBrowser implements BrowserStrategy {
    public Browser create() {
        return new ChromeBrowser();
    }
}

public class BrowserFactor {
    Map<String, BrowserStrategy> ctorStategy = ...; // I'd use DI, but this could be manually created.
    public Browser create(String type) {
        return type.create();
    }
}
```

The map/reflection way:

```
public class BrowserFactor {
    Map<String, Class<? extends Browser> clazz = ...; // I'd use DI, but this could be manually created.
    public Browser create(String type) {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }
}
```

My preference is to see if your DI framework can handle it for you. If not:

- Simple creation/fixed entity set - Enum or map/reflection
- Simple creation/expect the entity set will group - map/reflection
- Complex creation - map/strategy.

Answer (score 0):

```
int browserId = -1; // parse your CSV file and determine it.
Browser browser = BrowserFactory.getBrowserInstance(browserId);
```

---

```
public class ChromimumBrowser extends Browser {

            // Necessary code
}
```

All other browser classes should `extends`/`implements` `Browser`

---

```
public class BrowserFactory() {
     private static final int CHROME_BROWSER = 10;
     public Browser getBrowserInstance(int browserId) {
          Browser browser = null; 
          switch (browserId) {
             case CHROME_BROWSER:
                  browser = new ChromeBrowser();
                  break;
             ..
             ..
             default:
                    // Some fallout browser.
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: If i want to use :
`public enum BrowserType {
            firefox, ie, chrome
    }`

Comment: Doesn't matter what data type you use. I used this `int` identifier to just uniquely identify it.